# Overlap of Binary Categorical Data Flags Visualization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, binary

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df['A'] = 1 or 0
df['B'] = 1 or 0
df['C'] = 1 or 0
```

I want to produce a plot of overlap between the features with the same labels on X and Y axis like so

```
A  1 .4 .2 .1
B .1 1 .3 .4
C .4 .2 1 .5
D .1 .3 .7 1
   A  B  C D
```

Obviously, the diagonal will be 100%. For A B and B A, these numbers will differ as the denominator is of those with A, how many have B vs of those with B how many have A.

I think I know how to produce this visually, but not sure how to actually create the series with the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

This is matrix multiplication, then divided by the sum of the columns:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2, (10,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df.T.dot(df).div(df.sum())
```

Input:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  0  0  1
3  0  1  1  0
4  0  1  0  0
5  0  1  0  0
6  1  0  0  0
7  1  0  0  0
8  1  1  1  1
9  1  0  0  0
```

Output:

```
          A         B         C         D
A  1.000000  0.500000  0.666667  1.000000
B  0.428571  1.000000  1.000000  0.666667
C  0.285714  0.500000  1.000000  0.666667
D  0.428571  0.333333  0.666667  1.000000
```